# What to do with my react application already built?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I finished my react application, and I already built it. I also have my express app for my server side ready. I saw in a video that you can pass the files from the "build" folder to the "public" folder of the server app, but this was done in a basic json-server. I tried to do the same in my express app folder, but it didn't work. Could you please tell me where should I bring my "build" folder? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to serve you react app via express

You can try using below code to do it it will serve your react build folder via express

```
//define this static path which will point to your build folder inside your server folder

let root = path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/')
app.use(express.static(root))

//route you need to define in your main server file
app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'));
})
```

run the express app and then type the url in browser you will get redirected to react app